# Is there a name for the full-screen square in deferred shading?

Tags: graphics, 3d, terminology

In deferred shading, one uses a second render pass where a square covering the whole screen is drawn. Is there a commonly used name for this square? I want to write something about deferred  shading, and constantly callind it "the square" feels awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**full-screen quad**

That is how I am usually referring to it and it seems to be the most commonly used term in articles about post-processing in general. Technically you could call it a full-screen rectangle as well.

*Square* is not correct, as the aspect ratio of the rendered image could be != 1.